# How to write log parser query with $_.FullName in it in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

The following PowerShell script works.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\eventlogs -recurse -Filter *.evtx | foreach { cd $_.DirectoryName; pwd; & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\LogParser.exe' -stats:OFF -i:EVT -q:ON "SELECT * FROM [$_.FullName] WHERE EventID = '1101'" }
```

But I want to change the 'Security.evtx' with $_.FullName so the query runs on every file but just change that work. My output is as following:

```
PS C:\eventlogs> c:\ps\ps1.ps1

Error: Error retrieving files: Error opening file "C:\eventlogs\[application.evtx.FullName]": The system cannot find the file specified.
Error: Error retrieving files: Error opening file "C:\eventlogs\[security.evtx.FullName]": The system cannot find the file specified.
Error: Error retrieving files: Error opening file "C:\eventlogs\[system.evtx.FullName]": The system cannot find the file specified.
Path        
----        
C:\eventlogs
C:\eventlogs
C:\eventlogs


PS C:\eventlogs>
```

Comment: Don't use quotes, it's not allowing the expansion of the property. On the other, what's the particular reason of using this `LogParser.exe` when `Get-WinEvent` can read `.evtx` at ease?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I am not familiar with Get-WinEvent but I am parsing event log files saved in a folder. 'Security.evtx' in given in single quotes in working example. I have tried removing the quotes and replace it with `$_.FullName` and tried with the quotes, with square brackets etc but it's expanding the variable.

Comment: [1] the code you have posted is not valid. it will NEVER run since you have commented it out. [*grin*] ///// [2] **-post the code that actually triggers the error ... and post the FULL TEXT of the error._**

Comment: @Lee_Dailey posted full code and output. thanks.

Comment: `[$($_.FullName)]` like that inside your query string so it can expand. And https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-7.2 very easy to use.

Comment: @zar - i see that SantiagoSquarzon has pointed out the problem & the fix. great ... good to know that you have a solution ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey It didn't work, if make the change, it generates syntax error. I think part of the problem is to get syntax right for PowerShell. I posted a question for that here https://stackoverflow.com/q/72037957/841330

Comment: @zar - it looks like you need to FIRST get the correct syntax for using that command in powershell. the most "controllable & flexible" method is [usually] to use the `Start-Process` cmdlet.